# Openfire losing connection after sending composing messages

Tags: jquery, xmpp, openfire, strophe

Here we have a xmpp chat that uses strophe and jquery. On the server side we have a openfire server.

In the last 3 years, it was ok. But after implementing(2 weeks ago) a new functionality that send message composing warning that the user is typing, it´s Began a large number of lost connections during the conversations

Question, is it wrong to send composing messages (XEP-0085) in each keypress event ? This could be overloading the network or the openfire itself ?

Comment: I don't have direct expirience, but I will limit to send the composing iq just only of first key press (or better, when message length is 0 and change to any number and delete it when from any number return to 0, so you'll get copy/paste and canc actions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been thinking about this approach. However, it looks like you can not do this without use messy code. It would have mapping  event "keypress"  when the user stopped typing,  global variable ... But anyway, it seems there's not much more alternatives.